# Rails / SQL ... better to access database once and store data in array?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-activerecord, processing-efficiency

The heart of my app is a multi-conditional comparison using an input array and parameters stored in a few database tables.

I'm trying to make the process most efficient ... and I think this could lead to some good conversation about using memory vs. accessing a database.

Here's one example:

1. I have a `Merchant`, `MerchantUserRelation`, and `User` table.
2. Most of the data I need to store in a temporary array is from `MerchantUserRelation`, BUT at one point, I need to check if it's the user's birthday (`user.birthdate.today?`).

To me, it seems there are two options:

1. Create a temporary array with only data from `UserMerchantRelation` and then access the database separately for the `user.birthdate.today?` method (2 hits to the database), --or--
2. Create a slightly-larger temporary array with both the data from `UserMerchantRelation` AND `User` (and thus hit the database only once)

For this example I recognize the differences are EXTREMELY small (read: negligible), but what if the array sizes and # of database accesses required were much larger?

Thank you for any references and/or insights!

Answer (score 1):

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**  *- [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#cite_note-autogenerated268-2)*

As you said, the difference is negligible. And there is no absolute solution: memory or db hits. So why care them now? If your app grows and really met bottleneck, you can always profile and refactor to overcome it, by whatever workable methods.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I'd hoped -- that there isn't some obvious difference in efficiency of which I (being novice) was unaware.

Comment: @DanShev, yes, just go ahead following the common conventions, and solve problems only when they exist.